# Angular 13 after base href update, getting MIME type error

Tags: angular

Have a single NGINX, serving 3 applications. So to differentiate we have added base href in package.json as below and updated index.html of each application to reflect base href

**Package.json**

```
"csr:build:client:dev1": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --base-href /adminui/ --deploy-url /adminui/ --output-path=dist/DEV/public --aot=true",
```

And in **index.html**

```
<base href="/adminui">
```

Similar updates were made on other 2 apps. But I got below errors on browser console and page never loaded

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
polyfills.js:1 
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
vendor.js:1 
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
main.js:1 
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
runtime.js:1
```

Apps were running fine, if individually launched with no base href or using default.

Below are the changes I tried, along with above changes.

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
"target": "es2015",
```

to

```
"target": "es5",
```

Added in **app.module.ts** and **app.server.module.ts**

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
providers: [
 {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/adminui'}
]
```

But none worked, the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea to this. I think because of the changed `baseHref` the Angular application tries to download the scripts from a different URL as previously and NGINX returns to these requests a default HTML page (for example a 404 page). As the client expects JavaScript file and gets an HTML, the MIME error is displayed. I suggest to check the response content in the developer tools of the browser. If it is a default HTML from NGINX I suggest to configure NGINX that way, where he expects the resource file requests (such as JS files) on such URLs that are configured like the `baseHref` values.

Answer (score 0):

if you change the basehref in index.html same thing you need to add in angular.json as well.

for ex:

index.html

```
<base href="/adminui/">
```

angular.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/adminui/",
```

another change in angular.json

```
  "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets",
            "output": "/adminui/assets/"
          },
```